# Unusable desktops settings with nVidia

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 12.04, graphics, display

I am owner of nVidia GeForce GT 320M and I have two displays: external montior BenQ 1920x1080 and laptop's display 1366x768.

[image: NVIDIA X Server Settings]

Ubuntu with installed additional hardware drivers recognize my monitors just as a single monitor:

[image]

Similar behavior occurred also on 11.10 but Displays dialog wasn't so important as it is in 12.04:

- sticky edges make it painful to move the cursor from one display to another
- when saving a change in Displays dialog or during log in, the following error is displayed:

[image]

Displays dialog worked during the installation perfectly. I assume that the problem are nVidia drivers. Output of xrandr:

```
$ xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 3286 x 1080, current 3286 x 1080, maximum 3286 x 1080
default connected 3286x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   3286x1080      50.0*
```

My questions are:

- How to turn off sticky edges?
- How to get rid of that dialog after every login?
- Are there any alternative drivers which play well with Display dialog?
- How to get rid of nVidia drivers? I could only choose from version current and post-release updates:

[image: Additional Drivers]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the last screenshot in your post, you can press `Remove` on the bottom right. This will remove the closed Nvidia drivers, after a reboot, Ubuntu will use the open-source Nouveau driver. Normally, this works better with the Display system setting.

Comment: When post-release updates driver is installed, you have to downgrade to version current driver and afterwards you can remove it. I haven't noticed it before.

Comment: Ah you're right. I had the same experience a couple of days ago. I saw you had the current already activated, so I didn't mention.